# Force Automapper to use ConstructUsing even if nested entity is already created

Tags: c#, entity-framework, automapper

Please suppose my domain

```
public class Customer : Entity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Image Photo { get; set;}
    public int PhotoId { get; set; }
}

public class Image : Entity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public byte[] Content { get; set; }
}
```

Now suppose my models

```
public class CustomerModel : EntityModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ImageModel Photo { get; set;}
    public int PhotoId { get; set; }
}

public class ImageModel : EntityModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public byte[] Content { get; set; }
}
```

Suppose I have this customer on the database, attached to a DBContext:

```
customer = {
    Id : 1,
    Name : "Alexandre",
    PhotoId: 13,
    Photo : {
        Id: 13,
        Content: ABC
    }
}
```

and this model (posted by the user from a browser):

```
customerModel = {
    Id : 1,
    Name : "Alexandre",
    PhotoId: 0,
    Photo : {
        Id: 0,
        Content: XYZ
    }
}
```

So, how you can see, the user creates a new photo (Id == 0) that is not still saved to the database, and I will replace it on the entity.

The problem is : If I call

```
Mapper.Map(customerModel, customer)
```

AutoMapper will map customerModel.Photo from customer.Photo, instead of creates a new one, and entity framework will raise an exception because I can't change the PK of my image object.

Also, I can't just do

```
customer.Photo = null
```

before map the objects because my mapping are generics, and base classes does not knows structure of these objects. This is a very big application with many entities, I don't want execute this code for every nested property on every entity.

So I need something more genereic...

What I want: AutoMapper must to knows that these Photos are not the same (by comparing Ids) and so creates a new one instead of replace the same.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

This map forces the creation of new `Image` object accordingly to `Id` comparison:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<CustomerModel, Customer>()
    .BeforeMap((src, dest) => 
        dest.Photo = dest.Photo.Id != src.Photo.Id ? new Image() : dest.Photo);
```

**EDIT:** more generic approach:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<CustomerModel, Customer>().BeforeMap(Action);
Mapper.CreateMap<FooModel, Foo>().BeforeMap(Action);

private static void Action(EntityModel src, Entity dest)
{
    //get actual object properties via reflection, compare, re-create...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need something generics because my domain has 150 tables, and nested entities of many different types. I don't want to code this for each pair table /nested table.

Comment: @AlexandreTRINDADE, I don't know how to do it easily. However, if it is possible to compare objects with reflection, then the common `BeforeMap` action may help. I've added a sample to answer.